# Gradle absolute / relative path

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have the following problem. When I want to use a local jar in my Gradle dependencies.

If I just add:

```
compile files('libs/PushLinkAndroid-5.3.0.jar')
```

It doesn't work.

> C:\Users\Kai\AndroidStudioProjects\ProjectA\app\src\main\java\de\xyz\xxx\projecta\BaseActivity.java:21: error: package com.pushlink.android does not exist
>   import com.pushlink.android.PushLink;
>
> Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>   4 errors
>
> FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
>
>   > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or >--debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 6.543 secs

If i add the absolute path to the Jar, the project compiles and everything works finde:

```
compile files('C:/Users/Kai/AndroidStudioProjects/ProjectA/libs/PushLinkAndroid-5.3.0.jar')
```

Looks like there is something wrong with the Path but how could this be when the absolute Path works fine?

**EDIT:**
Build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "de.xyz.kai.migraenebook"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    //compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile project(':volley')
    debugCompile 'im.dino:dbinspector:3.2.1@aar'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
    //compile files('C:/Users/Kai/AndroidStudioProjects/MigraeneBook/libs/PushLinkAndroid-5.3.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/PushLinkAndroid-5.3.0.jar')
    //compile files('libraries/PushLinkAndroid-5.3.0.jar')
    //compile files('C:/Users/Kai/AndroidStudioProjects/MigraeneBook/libraries/PushLinkAndroid-5.3.0.jar')
}
```

NOTE: I tried different folders, the PushLink.jar is in "libs" and "libraries". It doesn't make a difference which command I use or comment out - absolute path is working, relative not.

Answer (score 16):

Try this, it would include all JARs in the local repository, so you wouldn't have to specify it every time:

```
dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Also, you should know that when referencing a file via

```
files("relative/path/to/a.jar")
```

path is evaluated relative to the buildscript this snippet is in. So when your `build.gradle` file is located in `/a/project/build.gradle`, then the jar should be in `/a/project/relative/path/to/a.jar`. 
In a multiproject gradle build you can put the the jar in a folder relative to the root - project and reference it in all subprojects via

```
rootProject.files("relative/to/root/a.jar")
```

So take this to account and re-check if your gradle settings are correct.

Comment: i tried, but this also doesn't work.
Looks like gradle has some problems with this relative path?

Comment: Generally it doesn't, so I guess it is some local problem. Try `gradlew clean`, sometimes it helps to fix this kind of problems.

Comment: Add your `build.gradle` to the question pls

Comment: build.gradle added @solar

Comment: Absolute Path:
C:\Users\Kai\AndroidStudioProjects\MigraeneBook\libs\*.jar
build.gradle within MigraeneBook

so relative path 
libs/*.jar should be correct

Answer (score 7):

If you call URL scheme path, you can use this example:

```
def path = "file://${projectDir}/ojdbc6.jar"
```

Answer (score 6):

Old question, but might help someone. 
I had the same problem, I had 2 libraries in the project root folder, and it didn't work with relative path. Add ../ before the relative path if your library is in your project's root folder.

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
...
implementation files('../library_name/libs/some.jar')
```

Answer (score 2):

Your libs folder is misplaced. You have to put it under `MigraeneBook/app` , not directly under `MigraeneBook`.

Answer (score 1):

First off in my opinion adding manual libs - if can be avoided - is bad practice because you need to maintain the lib and path yourself.

I had a quick look at the maven repo and it seems they don't have this specific lib there. This is what I'd expect:

```
compile('com.anypackage.name.PushLinkAndroid-5.3.0.jar')
```

Since this is probably not up to you than rather to the developer team of https://www.pushlink.com/changelog.xhtml it can't be helped.

Now to your problem: Did you start your build with --stacktrace?

From what I can gather from this

```
compile files('C:/Users/Kai/AndroidStudioProjects/ProjectA/libs/PushLinkAndroid-5.3.0.jar')
```

you're using a Windows system. This is troublesome at some points because Gradle expect the paths to look like this:

```
C:/Users/Kai/AndroidStudioProjects/ProjectA/libs/PushLinkAndroid-5.3.0.jar
```

My wild guess here is that gradle does something like this when you don't specify the path yourself:

```
C:\Users\Kai\AndroidStudioProjects\ProjectA\libs/PushLinkAndroid-5.3.0.jar
```

You can verify the behaviour with this gradle task:

```
task printBuildDir() {
    def buildDir = "${buildDir}"
    println buildDir
    def fixedDir = buildDir.replaceAll('\\\\', '/')
    println fixedDir
}
```

If my guess is correct, you got a couple of choices:

1. Use the full path
2. Use a gradle builtin path such as buildDir and replace the \ accordingly to the example (I'm not sure whether this works exactly like my example in dependencies tag, maybe you need to define a global variable yourself)
3. Get the developers of PushLink to put this lib up to Maven Repo

Answer (score 1):

Specifying each JAR filenames is also a posibility.

```
dependencies {
    compile files('lib/dependency_one.jar', 'lib/dependency_two.jar')
}
```

This will tell Gradle to include dependency_one.jar and dependency_two.jar during compilation.
To confirm that all required JARs included in compiling configuration, you can create this helper task,

```
task listJars << {
    configurations.compile.each { File file -> println file.name }
}
```

Then run it,

```
$ gradle -q listJars
hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar
antlr-2.7.6.jar
commons-collections-3.1.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
jta-1.1.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
```

Read more at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I copied it from the Android Studio IDE itself, as is command+c on the libs from one project and command+v to the libs of the other.  For some reason AS produces jar files with size zero... But hey I learned some new stuff about Gradle :)

Answer (score 0):

In **New Version** of `gradle:7.4.2'` if is added like this, there is a warning message and yellow color.

**avoid using absolute paths in .gradle files**

```
 implementation files('C:/Users/Mori/AndroidStudioProjects/InternalLibsKotlin/banner/build/outputs/aar/banner-debug.aar')
```

so you can Ignore this or do like this:

```
implementation files(/C:\/Users\/moriz\/AndroidStudioProjects\/InternalLibsKotlin\/banner\/build\/outputs\/aar\/banner-debug.aar/)
```