# How to avoid android studio to use absolute path?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I would like to force `gradle` file to use relative path when i add some `.jar` file as library in android studio. I couldn't find clear solution which would work for me.

When i add .jar file as library then i see something like following in my gradle file:

```
compile files('D:/Development/myApp/libs/my-jar-file.jar')
```

and i would like to have there following:

```
compile files('libs/my-jar-file.jar')
```

thank you for answers

Comment: The solution you have given should work. You might need to clean project to see changes. If it doesn't work, could you show your directory structure

Comment: Just dragging and dropping the .jar into the libs folder in Android Studio is probably the easiest solution.

Comment: @kevinpelgrims But there isn't necessarily a libs folder pre-existing in the project structure.

Comment: OP, why doesn't `compile files('libs/my-jar-file.jar')` work for you? Share the gradle console output.

Comment: See this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/76111801/12272687

Answer (score 0):

In the **New Version** of `gradle:7.4.2'` if is added like this, there is a warning message and yellow color.

**avoid using absolute paths in .gradle files**

```
 implementation files('C:/Users/Mori/AndroidStudioProjects/InternalLibsKotlin/banner/build/outputs/aar/banner-debug.aar')
```

so you can **Ignore** it as the old suggestion mentioned about it

https://googlesamples.github.io/android-custom-lint-rules/checks/GradlePath.md.html

or **Just do it like this**:

```
implementation files(/C:\/Users\/moriz\/AndroidStudioProjects\/InternalLibsKotlin\/banner\/build\/outputs\/aar\/banner-debug.aar/)
```