# How to reference other classesdir in Gradle multi-project build

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, spring-boot-gradle-plugin, gradle-multi-project-build

I am building an API using spring boot. I'm using gradle and a multi-project build set up where I have a **services-lib** project and an **api** project that depends on the **services-lib**.

Running the **api:bootRun** tasks in the api project works perfectly fine, but now I'm trying to add the ability to trigger an spring-boot-devtools [automatic restart](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-spring-boot.html#using-boot-devtools-restart), which requires the bootRun task to have the **service-lib** classdir in it's classpath(not the jar that is added by the multi-project dependency).

Adding this to my api's build.gradle does trigger the automatic restart when I run the api:build task (where "C:/foo/bar" is the absolute path to my multi-project root directory).

```
bootRun {
    classpath += files('C:/foo/bar/services-lib/build/classes/java/main')
}
```

My question is, instead of having to hard code that path, can I set it using something like project(':services-lib')?

Comment: have you checked this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32082470/6021740

Answer (score 0):

Well I did figure this out thanks to Kidus' suggestion.

```
bootRun {
    bootRun.systemProperty 'spring.profiles.active', 'dev'
    classpath += files('../services-lib/build/classes/java/main')
}
```

It still means if I change anything about the build output in the **services-lib** project I have to change it hear but at least now when others check out the project now it will work for them.